# Scraping json with python requests

Tags: python, json, request

This is not my first time scraping data but it sure feels like it.

```
import csv
import requests
import os

outfile = open("Labs_StartingGoalies.csv","a",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
header=[
    "Home_Tm"]

writer.writerow(header)

req = requests.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/lines/4/12-20-2017/startinggoalies') 
data = req.json()['GoalieMatchups']

for i, teams in enumerate(data):
    for i, team in enumerate(teams['Properties']):
        print (team)
```

**Output:**

```
EventId
EventDate
EventDateTime
TimeOfDay
Stadium
HomeTeam
HomeEventTeamId
HomeGoalie
HomeTwitterName
HomePrimarySourceKey
HomeGoalieId
HomeGoalieSalary_DK
HomeGoalieSalary_FD
HomeGoalieStatus
HomeGoalieText
HomeModifiedDate
HomeSourceText
HomeSourceURL
HomeMoneyLine
HomeMoneylineChange
HomeVegasPoints
VisitorTeam
VisitorEventTeamId
VisitorGoalie
VisitorTwitterName
VisitorPrimarySourceKey
VisitorGoalieId
VisitorGoalieSalary_DK
VisitorGoalieSalary_FD
VisitorGoalieStatus
VisitorGoalieText
VisitorModifiedDate
VisitorSourceText
VisitorSourceURL
VisitorMoneyLine
VisitorMoneylineChange
VisitorVegasPoints
```

**Next Code:**

```
import csv
import requests
import os

outfile = open("Labs_StartingGoalies.csv","a",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
header=[
    "Home_Tm"]

writer.writerow(header)

req = requests.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/lines/4/12-20-2017/startinggoalies') 
data = req.json()['GoalieMatchups']

for i, teams in enumerate(data):
    for i, team in enumerate(teams['Properties']):
        HomeTeam = team['HomeTeam']
        print (HomeTeam)
```

**Error:**
`File "C:/Python36/Projects/NHL/Labs_Teams.py", line 17, in <module>
       HomeTeam = team['HomeTeam']
       TypeError: string indices must be integers`

This `Json` is a little difficult to read. Usually I use `Mozilla` for it but it's not displaying in the normal manner. I would like to start pulling the data out of the list's in the first `output` but all of the different attempts come up short. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: It looks like you are enumerating over the keys of the properties dict, which happen to be strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop should be modified as below,

```
for i, teams in enumerate(data):
    HomeTeam = teams['Properties']['HomeTeam']
    print (HomeTeam)
```

This will output

```
Columbus Blue Jackets
Philadelphia Flyers
Calgary Flames
```

You don't need the inner loop since `teams['Properties']` is a dictionary, not a list.

**Edit**: Also, since you are not using the counter, you don't need to enumerate data,which is already a list

```
for teams in data:
    HomeTeam = teams['Properties']['HomeTeam']
    print (HomeTeam)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you use enumerate?
You probably want to do something like this:

```
for teams in data:
    HomeTeam = teams['Properties']['HomeTeam']
    print (HomeTeam)
```

Result:

```
Columbus Blue Jackets
Philadelphia Flyers
Calgary Flames
```